# pdp-11 assembly-error 8-illegal charcater

Tags: assembly, pdp-11

Good evening
i am a new programmer ,trying to compile the below code at assembly using pdp-11 simulator.
But im stack with errors,i'm sure about the syntax but can't define where the error or what to change.
the code :

```
movb @#tkb, r0
bic #177600, r0
cmpb #’$, r0
beq seton
```

error descripe:
"error 8-illegal character" for the line "cmpb #'$, r0".

anyone knows why that is? and how should i write it? The point is to stop the loop when i get the '$ char.

Comment: Did you copy/paste that code from a PDF file or web page? Your `#’$` looks like it might not be using a proper ASCII single quote. Just a hunch. It should be `#'$`. Try retyping that line manually.

Comment: @lurker is correct: I ran `hexdump -C` in a terminal window and pasted the code from your question:  `23 e2 80 99 24`, i.e. `#...$` so it's a 3-byte utf-8 character.

Comment: I found a duplicate by searching on `code:"’"` on SO (copy-pasting your non-ASCII character)